# curl stopped to post anything

Tags: bash, curl

In the below dev-netpro.sh script 'curl' does not post anything if my $FWK (i.e. '8fwk3_dev 2fwk0_dev' - could be up to 9 words) and $CON (in the example it is series of digits:'72 43 172 28021 8261 14015 325 24 524') get more than one word

```
[Expert@WAL-NEW-VSX-02:0]# cat dev-netpro.sh 
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
        FWK=$(top -b -n 1 | egrep 'fwk' |  awk '{print $9 $NF}')
        CON=$(vsx stat -l | egrep 'number' | awk '{print $3}')       
TIME=`date +"%T"` 
echo $HOSTNAME, $TIME, $FWK, $CON
echo '{"WAL-VSX-02": "['"$TIME"','"$FWK"','"$CON"']"}'
curl -ik -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"WAL-VSX-02": "['"$TIME"','"$FWK"','"$CON"']"}' -X POST "https://10.199.107.11:8880/test"  
sleep 2 
done
[Expert@WAL-NEW-VSX-02:0]#
```

See the output below:

```
    [Expert@WAL-NEW-VSX-02:0]# ./dev-netpro.sh 
    WAL-NEW-VSX-02, 12:53:17, 8fwk3_dev 2fwk0_dev, 72 43 172 28021 8261 14015 325 24 524
    {"WAL-VSX-02": "[12:53:17,8fwk3_dev
    2fwk0_dev,72
    43
    172
    28021
    8261
    14015
    325
    24
524]"}
```

......nothing

Answer (score 1):

Newline came from these two commands run at the beginning of the script . After

> FWK=$(echo $FWK|tr -d '\n')
>   CON=$(echo $CON|tr -d '\n')

it worked ! Appreciate your help a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around that content inside of the JSON object try and you need to quote the entire string so that spaces inside the variables don't make anything after the space get treated as a separate argument.

`echo "{\"WAL-VSX-02\": [\"$TIME\",\"$FWK\",\"$CON\"]}"`

The way you had it before there were (single) quotes around several components of the string which works but if there are spaces in any of the vars then the shell parses it as separate strings.  This way the whole thing is quoted so the shell will parse it as one string.

Comment: no change after -d '{"WAL-VSX-02": "["'"$TIME"'","'"$FWK"'","'"$CON"'"]"}' . It worked well if $FWK was just 8fwk3_dev and $CON was i.e. 34

Comment: i.e. {"WAL-VSX-02":"[13:21:52,4fwk3_dev,27512]"} it works well

Comment: See my edits.  There was a second problem that I hadn't noticed at first.

Comment: same thing, I think problem is that there are \n between words..

Comment: How did the `\n`'s get there?  When you did the first echo it was just spaces between the words.

Comment: `davidwk ~ # FWK='8fwk3_dev 2fwk0_dev'
davidwk ~ # CON='72 43 172 28021 8261 14015 325 24 524'
davidwk ~ # TIME=$(date +"%T")
davidwk ~ # echo "{\"WAL-VSX-02\": [\"$TIME\",\"$FWK\",\"$CON\"]}"
{"WAL-VSX-02": ["15:50:20","8fwk3_dev 2fwk0_dev","72 43 172 28021 8261 14015 325 24 524"]}`

Comment: Sorry, that's really hard to read in the comments but, basically, it didn't put the `\n`'s in for me.

Answer (score 0):

To include arbitrary strings in a JSON document, you need to encode the strings as JSON strings properly.  This is best done with a utility that understands JSON, such as `jq`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    fwk=$( top -b -n 1 | awk '/fwk/ { print $9 $NF }' )
    con=$( vsx stat -l | awk '/number/ { print $3 }' )

    printf -v now '%(%T)T' -1

    jq -cn \
        '{ "WAL-VSX-02": $ARGS.positional }' \
        --args "$now" "$fwk" "$con" |
    curl --silent --show-error \
        --json @- 'https://10.199.107.11:8880/test'

    sleep 2
done
```

In the above code, a JSON document is created using `jq`.  The document will contain a single JSON object with the key `WAL-VSX-02`.  The value of the key will be an array whose elements are the strings listed after `--args` at the very end of the command.

The JSON object is piped to `curl` which reads it with `--json @-`.

To see the posted JSON in each iteration, insert `tee` as a new pipeline step between `jq` and `curl`.

Given the data that I can see in your question, this would generate and post a JSON document equivalent to

```json
{
  "WAL-VSX-02": [
    "12:53:17",
    "8fwk3_dev\n2fwk0_dev",
    "72\n43\n172\n28021\n8261\n14015\n325\n24\n524"
  ]
}
```

(But on a single line, due to the `-c` option we use with `jq`.)

With a tiny bit more effort, we could post those multi-line strings as separate arrays. Just use a slightly modified `jq` expression that splits the given strings (apart from the first) on newlines:

```bash
jq -cn \
    '{ "WAL-VSX-02": ( $ARGS.positional | .[1:] |= map(split("\n")) ) }' \
    --args "$now" "$fwk" "$con"
```

This would generate the equivalent of

```json
{
   "WAL-VSX-02": [
      "12:53:17",
      [ "8fwk3_dev", "2fwk0_dev" ],
      [ "72", "43", "172", "28021", "8261", "14015", "325", "24", "524" ]
   ]
}
```